# What should the election voting badge be named?

Tags: discussion, badges, election

To recognize and encourage those who participate in the election process, we are adding a few badges.  First, we'll be adding a **Caucus** badge for visiting the election (we double checked the spelling), this can be awarded multiple times and will be retroactively awarded for previous election participation.

Another badge we want to add is for *voting in the election*, we'll be adding this in the next few days but want to get a great name for it, the names thrown out internally are:

- **Rocked the Vote** (trademarked, we may have issues here)
- **I Voted**
- **Hanging Chad**
- **Ballot Stuffing**

What name should this badge have?  Give us your best.

Comment: I'm incredibly surprised there was never a [meta-tag:badge-request] for this... They suggest them for everything else...

Comment: Electorate is already taken, sadly...

Comment: I'd personally avoid the ones with somewhat negative connotations, like "Ballot Stuffing" or "Hanging Chad". It is supposed to be encouraging *positive* behavior, no? ;)

Comment: I'm from Chicago: "Vote Early, Vote Often", where we also have "Ghost Voting".

Comment: I hated having the name Chad during that election!

Comment: "Hanging Chad" also sounds like something that doesn't make any sense outside the US.

Comment: Perhaps "Community Voice"?

Comment: I think **We the People** sounds pretty cool.

Comment: Can we get a silver badge for voting X times in an election?

Comment: @Oded since Electorate is taken, **Electric** looks like second best to me

Comment: [*mic drop*](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=473313#473313). I will also accept "By Popular Demand", just to confuse [Popular Demand](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/popular-demand)

Comment: I like **Partisan** but it has a negative connotation in the US.

Comment: Hm? I though voting was anonymous, and that included the fact of whether you voted or not, not just whom you voted for... Bad idea...

Comment: @YannisRizos Why don't you feel the same way about Supporter/Critic/Civic Duty/Electorate?  Voting on posts is supposed to be just as anonymous as voting in elections, right?

Comment: @YannisRizos there's a count of anonymous votes in everyone's profile as well...I don't think it's a concern in this case, there's no harmful information being shared. It's more of making voting in the election a cool thing to do.

Comment: I won't suggest Gerrymandering then :)

Comment: @Danielδ Apples and oranges. Everyone votes on posts, not everyone votes on elections. And, for example, the only thing you know about someone having critic is that they downvoted a random post amongst thousands, however with the voter badge you know what election they voted in...

Comment: What difference would it make if you knew which election?  Basically, the point of anonymity is to prevent users from doing anything reprehensible to another user whose decision(s) they may disagree with.  I don't know anyone who would do something vengeful to me just because I voted, period.

Comment: `[status-hasvoted]`

Comment: [**Long Live the King**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_is_dead._Long_live_the_King.), just to see Evan Carroll flame about the mods being all-powerful monarchical dictators.

Comment: The badge-accumulators will resort to "Ballot Stuffing" - might as well call it a representative name. Ducks and all...

Comment: "I Voted" will be cool, but i was thinking if we have more options too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, we already used the terms "Electorate" and "Vox Populi" for other voting badges, but [**Constituent**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/constituent) is still open.

Comment: I'm not completely comfortable with "Constituent"... we're electing moderators, not politicians.

Comment: @PopularDemand: The definition isn't necessarily tied to politics: "One that authorizes another to act as a representative".

Comment: I am aware. But still. Feels weird to me.

Answer (score 19):

**I Voted**

[image: I Voted]

I like this because it's a play on the corny stickers here in the USA. It might be too US-centric because of that, but it's also a clear description of what the badge is for. I wasn't clear on if "the names thrown out internally" meant "thrown out there" as in "suggested" or "thrown out" as in "rejected... didn't see it as an answer so I figured I would post it myself. It's too good to pass up!

Comment: sounds like an Apple thing :) "iVoted"

Comment: I also support **I VOTED**

Answer (score 12):

**by the people**

for the badge for voting in the election

Answer (score 8):

This is tricky, since there are so many kinds of voting on the site, and so many voting-related terms are already in use.

Since voting in moderator elections is open to all non-drive-by users (it only takes 150 rep to participate, after all), it's similar to voting in a **Referendum** or a **Plebiscite** in a way that voting on questions and answers isn't.

Comment: Can you make this two answers? I would vote for *Plebiscite*, if I could do so without voting for *Referendum*.

Comment: *Plebiscite* would work very, very well.

Comment: Referendum would be for voting in five or more consecutive moderator elections?

Comment: Plebiscite sounds like a mineral harvested from the bodies of Plebeians.

Comment: @jcolebrand what's the significance of five?

Comment: That it's more than 1? Other than that, nothing in particular. Also, 6 to 8 is so vague, but that could work.

Comment: I think the negative connotation adds weight to the word... it's a "power to the people" sort of word.

Comment: I always take words seriously. They're all we have man. You can't go "oh, that word makes me feel bad inside" when it has a concrete meaning. You can, however, talk about how it's a trigger for you based on a past experience. But we can't say "oh, you can't say the word 'Nazi' because that's illegal", words have to be independent of regulation (internal or external) so we can have a discussion about the things the words represent. I believe penultimately in the power of words over all things.

Comment: Seems like the whole point of this question is to analyze words and phrases for meaning, no?

Answer (score 8):

By Popular Demand

(seriously, 30 chars?)

Comment: We wouldn't want @PopularDemand to get a big head... :P

Comment: Oh, it's far, far too late for that, @Flimzy. See how my avatar isn't a photo of me? It's because my head is already too big to fit.

Answer (score 5):

I like @PopularDemand's suggestion of:

### Plebiscite

Answer (score 5):

What about a silly pun:

**Modevoter**

Comment: Nothing improves the quality of my day like a silly pun.

Comment: This is the most underrated answer of all imo

Answer (score 4):

## Ballot

Answer (score 3):

**Yea or Nay**

or I think the original

**Yay or Nay**

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/817/is-yay-or-nay-an-acceptable-alternative-to-yea-or-nay

Comment: This has the same problem as "Electoral College." It's a somewhat voting-related term, but it doesn't describe the system of voting used in moderator elections here at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Technically there's no "Nay" vote...

Comment: @BenBrocka: Isn't there in the primary?

Answer (score 0):

["None of the Above"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/None_of_the_above) gets my vote...

If nothing else, it is obscure enough that people will look it up.

Comment: Technically you should get such a badge by not voting

Comment: I think it's so overused that nobody will look it. Also, since it is "designed to allow the voter to indicate disapproval of all of the candidates in a voting system", it's inherently negative towards the moderator candidates. I can say I have never felt the anywhere near the same disapproval of all of the candidates in a SO election as I have for US elections! If only real-life elections were like SO elections the world would be a better place, IMO.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException: that's the difference between SO and the US...you've actually got to prove your usefulness on SO (something money can't buy).

Comment: Well said @sixlettervariables!

Answer (score 0):

**I Participated**

filler text to fill out 30 characters.

Comment: In what?  [filler]

Answer (score -1):

**Democracy in Action** (just for voting)

Although I don't think it would work due to it having 3 words...

Comment: or just "Democratic"

Comment: @LarsTech I was thinking about that, but then all the US **Republicans** would yell at me....

Comment: or "Democracy Inaction"...

Answer (score -3):

Voted for moderator so name it

VO: from Voted
MO: starting two char of moderator 
TOR: Last three of Moderator

**VOMOTOR**